# How can I combine Dynamic plots saved in named variables inside a DynamicModule?

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

I am creating a few separate plots that I want to be updated dynamically. I want to combine the plots so they are a single plot. Normally, I would use `Show` for this. The following toy example produces the output I would like, except for the `doesNotShow` plot:

```
DynamicModule[{somePolys, xa, xb, dx, xbScaled, fbScaled, x, 
  doesNotShow, sf = 1, x0, fa, fb, points, staticPlot},
 somePolys = {1 + x, 0.5 - 0.1*x, 1 - 0.1*x^2, 
   1 - x - 0.2*x^2 + 0.05*x^3};
 xa = x0;
 xb = x0 + dx;
 xbScaled = x0 + dx*sf;
 fa = somePolys /. x -> xa;
 fb = somePolys /. x -> xb;
 staticPlot = Plot[somePolys, {x, -2, 2}];
 points = MapThread[{{xa, #1}, {xb, #2}} &, {fa, fb}];
 doesNotShow = 
  ListPlot[points + 0.5, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]];
 {
   Slider[Dynamic[x0], {-1, 2}],
   Slider[Dynamic[dx], {0.1, 2}, Exclusions -> {0}],
   Dynamic[Show[
     {
      staticPlot,
      ListPlot[points],
      ListPlot[points, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black],
      doesNotShow
      }, ImageSize -> Medium]]
   } // Column
 ]
```

This produces the following output. Note that the `doesNotShow` plot does not show (or update dynamically):
[image: Output of toy example]
I would like to save *all* of the plots in named variables like the plot `doesNotShow`. How can I save the plots in named variables and get them to dynamically update in a dynamic `Show`?